# Как правильно писать/говорить: "джинс", "джинсов"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Объясните, пожалуйста, в каких случаях нужно говорить/писать "джинс", а в каких "джинсов".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: джинсов, верна только одна форма, что указывается в словарях.

Правило такое:

Ряд существительных в русском языке употребляется только во множественном числе, например: ножницы, грабли, ворота.  Выбор окончания в Р.падежа для них зависит от основы, например:

шаровары – шаровар, вилы – вил, потемки – потемок – нулевое окончание,

лохмотья – лохмотьев, консервы – консервов – окончание ОВ/ЕВ,

будни –  будней - окончание ЕЙ, форма буден  устарела, ясли – Яслей.

Некоторые существительные в Р.падеже имеют две формы, например: грабли  – грабель и грАблей.

Поэтому форму Р.п. таких существительных следует контролировать по словарю, здесь важна традиция и удобное произношение.